# How to shop boostrap button in line with headline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to show a `<h4>` in line with a `<button>`:

```
    <h4 style="display:inline-block;">headline</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-dropdown-flat" type="button">
        <span>Button</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/punwaew1/1/

Result: the two elements are shown below each other. Why?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/punwaew1/2/

Comment: because div bydefault take div:block and its taking full width.

Comment: Check my answer if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `display` on a `<div>` element is `display:block;`. You have to set the `display:inline-block;` to the `<div>` too!

**Simply add the following rule (https://jsfiddle.net/punwaew1/5/):**

```
div.dropdown {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `h4` and `.dropdown` are on the same level. Set `display: inline-block` for the elements on the same level to make them align.

```css
h4,
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>headline</h4>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-dropdown-flat" type="button">
    <span>Button</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: one suggestion please don't add vertical-align: top in all example when its not needed. Better create new code section whenever you are giving answer rather then copy the last one :)

Comment: @Leothelion The default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline` which is not Ok for many situations. So as for me its better to explicitly define the alignment that is needed.

Comment: ok but as far as i can see is that we can get the desired output without using it but leave it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add line style to `<div class="dropdown" **style="display:inline-block;"**>`

**[DEMO 1](https://jsfiddle.net/punwaew1/3/)**

OR use proper rows and column of bootstrap to get best results and consitency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fiddle Just give `display: inline-block` to dropdown div
https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/punwaew1/4/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without any extra css. So in-order to make your button inline with your headline, place the button between the `<h2></h2>` heading tag.

Structure:

```
<h1>Headline 
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-dropdown-flat" type="button">
    Button
  </button>
</h1>
```

Have a look at your updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/punwaew1/6/)